# How can I implement a multi join in Typo3 via userfunction?

Tags: mysql, typo3-6.2.x

I want to implement the following sql query:

```
    SELECT title 
    FROM sys_category
    JOIN sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local
    JOIN tt_content ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = tt_content.uid
    WHERE tt_content.uid = 645
```

If I execute this query directly via phpmyadmin it is working, but if I try the following via userfunction the content of $row is false, so I think the syntax for my multi join must be wrong. Hope you can help me :)

```
public function getCategories()
{
    $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery
    ( 
        'title',
        'sys_category JOIN sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local JOIN tt_content ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = tt_content.uid',
        'sys_category.uid = 645'
    );
    $row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc( $res );
    var_dump( $row );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the problem was, that I used

```
'sys_category.uid = 645'
```

instead of

```
'tt_content.uid = 645'
```